# VirtualBox Share a 3G dongle connection in windows 7

Tags: php, virtualbox, 3g, network-share, turnkeylinux.org

I am running the Turnkey Linux LAMP appliance in VirtualBox and need to update the PHP.  I want to do it using apt-get but I can't figure out how to share my computers 3G dongle connection.  I am running windows 7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out myself, for all interested:

In network settings share the 3g dongle connection
Install microsoft loopback adapter
On the appliance settings set the network settings to bridged adapter - loopback adapter
After booting up appliance setup static ip,

Answer (score 0):

You're Host's connection should carry over to your Guest (unless your 3G tether requires a special network adapter).

Comment: It doesn't carry over.  I have tried all of the network settings without any luck :(